# How do I get the value of a bool from a JSON in Swift3/Swift4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

```
let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

if responseString["is_valid"] == true {
    print("Login Successful")
} else {
    print("Login attempt failed")
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of `"is_valid"` from `responseString` dictionary. However, I have no idea how. Everything I've tried has failed.

`responseString` looks like this when outputted via `print()`:

```
{
  "is_valid": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
if let responseString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Bool] {
    if responseString!["is_valid"] == true {
        print("Login Successful")
    } else {
        print("Login attempt failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a solution using Swift 4 new *encoding/decoding framework* ;)

```
let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: Bool].self, from: data)
if response?["is_value"] {
    print("Login Successful")
} else {
    print("Login attempt failed")
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't reommend decoding to `[String: Bool]` but decoding to Swift native dictionary type `[String: Any]` it isn't possible. So if you want to do it in one line `if (try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: Bool].self, from: data))?["is_value"] == true {`

Comment: @LeoDabus `Any` doesn’t conform to `Decodable` so no luck there ;)

Comment: I know thats why I said it isn't possible :) Considering that it is just an authentication response and there is only one value it shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON in the `data` with `JSONSerialization`:

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
    let isValue = json?["is_value"] as? Bool else { 
        // handle the failure to find `is_value` however you'd like here
        return 
}

if isValue { ... }
```

Comment: Sure. But my broader point was that I didn't like the `as? [String: Bool]` of the accepted answer because if the JSON happened to include anything besides booleans like `is_value`, it would fail. Using `[String: Any]` and then deferring the cast to `Bool` until you retrieve `is_value` is safer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you could find the Boolean value and keep it stored in a Struct

```
{
"is_valid" = true
}

struct Session: Codable {
var isValid: Bool

 //Create a coding key so you can match the struct variable name to JSON data key
 private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
   case isValid = "is_valid"
 }

 //Initialises and decodes the JSON data to fill your struct
 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
   let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
   self.isValid = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isValid)
 }

}
```

Now let's say your loading from a JSON file within the app.

```
func loadJSONData(){
  guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myJSONFile", withExtension: "json") else { return }
 do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()

      //decode data and populate Session struct
      guard let jsonData = try? decoder.decode(Session.self, from: data) else {return}

      if jsonData.isValid {
          print("DO SOMETHING HERE)
    }
  } 
}
```